# Black Screen when stream video with avkit

Tags: swift, avfoundation, media-player, avkit

Hi I want to stream remote video on my app. URL is: http://test.ext/myvideo.mkv

I use AVKit with this code but screen and audio not works. I see only progress bar that go forward.

```
         let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
        controller.player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)


        // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
        self.present(controller, animated: true) {
                player.play()
        }
```

Comment: check for the frame, it might be ZERO..

Comment: A mkv can be read with AVPlayer like that? If you have a URL, maybe test it in Safari.

Comment: When I run a URL in safari appears play with slash

Comment: With slash? you mean it cant' be played

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVPlayer don't support mkv video format.

Anyone have a solution for playing all video format ?

I've tested MobileVLCKit but it's too heavy (1,5Go)...